# Insert value into table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have below SQL query, am trying to insert data into test table, but I got another requirement that I need to insert the employee number along with his/her name.

Example 
firstname : 71853-osama

My question is, How I can insert two values into one attribute 
I tried this

```
 badgeno +'-'+ convert(nvarchar(100),cEmpname) as cEmpname
```

but it didn't work

```
insert into PT ( 
      [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[FirmID]
      ,[Note]
      ,[City]
      ,[ThirdPartyId]
      ,[RegisteredBy]
      ,[Registered]
      ,[LastUpdatedBy]
      ,[LastUpdated]
                 )

     SELECT distinct 
     convert(nvarchar(100),cEmpname) as cEmpname 
      ,convert(nvarchar(100),cJobTitle) as cJobTitle
      ,'2' as FirmID
      ,convert(nvarchar(500),sort1) as sort1
      ,convert(nvarchar(255),cnationality) as cnationality
     , badgeno as 'ThirdPartyId'
    ,'admin' as RegisteredBy
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  as Registered
     ,'admin' as  LastUpdatedBy
     , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as LastUpdated


      FROM [TrailBlazerNG].[dbo].[payper] where lactive = '1' 
      and not exists ( select 1 from PT where payper.badgeno = PT.ThirdPartyId)
```

Comment: Actually don't do this - Never store multiple values in a single column

Comment: you can use concat_ws function of mysql to concat string

Comment: @CharveeShah : It does not really apply when the question is tag as sql-server.

Comment: @juergend why i cant please, can you explain further

Comment: @CharveeShah can you show me please

Comment: Please read about DB *normalization*. If you store multiple values in a single column you will get into problems when you need to seperate the data in your selects or try to select data depending only on one value, but stored two.

Comment: make the datatype varchar...and go ahead with the concat i.e $id_num.'-'.$first_name

Comment: @Arion when i saw,mysql tag was there.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
insert into PT ([FirstName],[FirmID],[Note],[City],[ThirdPartyId],[RegisteredBy],[Registered],[LastUpdatedBy],[LastUpdated])

 SELECT distinct 
 convert(nvarchar(100),badgeno)+'-'+convert(nvarchar(100),cEmpname) as cEmpname 
  ,convert(nvarchar(100),cJobTitle) as cJobTitle
  ,'2' as FirmID
  ,convert(nvarchar(500),sort1) as sort1
  ,convert(nvarchar(255),cnationality) as cnationality
 , badgeno as 'ThirdPartyId'
,'admin' as RegisteredBy
,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  as Registered
 ,'admin' as  LastUpdatedBy
 , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as LastUpdated


  FROM [TrailBlazerNG].[dbo].[payper] where lactive = '1' 
  and not exists ( select 1 from PT where payper.badgeno = PT.ThirdPartyId)
```